# Python non-greedy regular expression returning greedy match

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract a list of hyperlink text (as well as the url and date) from a website http://www.efsa.europa.eu/en/news using regular expressions.

An example of this text would be "Veterinary drug residues in animals and food: compliance with safety levels still high"

However, my expression is returning more text than is required e.g.

```
<span class="field-content"><a href="/en/news/veterinary-drug-residues-animals-and-food-compliance-safety-levels-still-high">Veterinary drug residues in animals and food: compliance with safety levels still high"
```

Here is my code:

```
import bs4, requests, re


res = requests.get('http://www.efsa.europa.eu/en/news')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
elems = soup.select('body > div.l-page > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.view-content.news-page-display')

a = str(elems[0])

text = re.findall(r'">(.+?)</a></span> </div>',a)

for i in range (len(text)):
    print(text[i]+'\n')
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this? I have been trying for an hour and now given up :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have BeautifulSoup at your disposal, why are you resorting to regexes?

Comment: If you are already using ```BeautifulSoup```, why not use it to find ```<a>``` elements as well?

Comment: For longer explanations, see duplicate threads linked at the top, in short: you should have written `>([^>]+)</a></span> </div>`, but to actually have no trouble like this, just go on with BS. Regex is not necessary here, to just get the text from the `a` tag.

Comment: I am using BeautifulSoup to get the whole website content and then regex to find the news headlines, hyperlinks, and dates. The code iterates over 20 sites with a regex for each site's data. Is this not right? I am brand new to python and just learning at the moment.

Comment: @blahblahvvvvv you can get then anchors with `el =soup.select('div.view-content.news-page-display a')` Then each `el` will have the link in `for a in el: a['href']`

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thank you! I wish I had known this when I started my project weeks ago!

Comment: You can simply match `.*> *` and replace it with an empty string. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4bX3vk/2/). As `.*` is greedy, it will gobble up all characters, including `>`'s, until it reaches the last `>`. It will then consume that character and any following spaces. In other words, it will consume all characters up to the beginning of he string you wish to extract.